# How to save .wav to s3 bucket from URL in lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a url for a .wav file. I'd like to save it to an S3 bucket from a Lambda function.
Do I have to download it first?

What's the best way to do this?

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // imports
  const fs = require('fs');
  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  AWS.config.update({ region: process.env.REGION || 'us-east-1' })
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();


  // get URL
  const body = parseBody(event['body']);
  const url = body.url;

  // download file?
  // HOW TO DO THIS using async?
  const file_name = magic_save(url)

  // upload to S3
  var bucketName =  `some_bucket`;
  var keyName = 'audio.wav';
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(file_name);
  var params = { 'Bucket': bucketName, 'Key': keyName, 'Body': fileContent };
  try {
      console.log('saving...');
      const data = await s3.putObject(params).promise();
      console.log("Successfully saved object to " + bucketName + "/" + keyName);
      } catch (err) {
          console.log('err');
          console.log(err);

      };
```

Answer (score 2):

Best will be to stream the file directly to s3 like this

```
const got = require("got");
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const s3Client = new aws.S3();
const Bucket = 'somebucket';
const Key = "some/audio.wav";

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // get URL
  const body = parseBody(event['body']);
  const url = body.url;

  const stream = got.stream(url);
  const response = await s3Client.upload({Bucket, Key, Body: stream}).promise();
  console.log(response);
};
```